# Water heater wires got wet

Tags: water-heater

My water heater line was leaking, I replace it already however, they tray that hold the wires has water. If I dry it up would the water be ok or will it cause a fire, I already turned the breaker off

Comment: If just wires, drying them should be all you need.  If it is something else like electrical controls or electronics, then some damage might have happen.

Answer (score 2):

Simply drying them should be sufficient.  **EXCEPT** If the water contained a lot of rust or sediment you need to be absolutely certain that no bare metal wiring got wet, since the rust can conduct electricity.

Answer (score 0):

In many Heaters I have seen, the wires come from top inside metal conduit.

There is no water there at any time.

But in your case, just dry them with hair dryer and continue, unless the water got into the conduit.

The lowest part that is inside the heater are the wires for the heating element, which might get wet.